# A is affine iff it satisfies convexity condition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

> Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m $ is affine function iff $ A(tx+(1-t)y)=tA(x)+(1-t)A(y)$
>   $\forall t\in \mathbb{R},x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I can prove that

$A$ is affine then it satisfies  $A(tx+(1-t)y)=tA(x)+(1-t)A(y) \ \forall t\in \mathbb{R},x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

But I could not prove converse ?

> A mapping $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$  is said to be affine if there exist linear map $B:R^n\to R^m$ and element $b\in R^m$ such that $A(x)=B(x)+b$

Any Hint will be appreciated .

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use the fact that $B$ is linear, then the converse will follow. Lookup definition of linear maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $B(x):=A(x)-A(0)$. Then show that $B$ is linear:
$$
B(t x) = A(tx)-A(0) = A(tx+(1-t)0)-A(0) = tA(x)+(1-t)A(0)-A(0) = t(A(x)-A(0)) = tB(x)
$$
and
$$
B(x+y) = 2B(\frac x2+\frac y2)= 2(\frac 12B(x)+\frac 12B(y))=B(x)+B(y).
$$
Then set $b:=A(0)$.